# Superscript j7 for minor chord

Tags: guitar, chords

I already asked this as an answer... beginners error!
What does superscript j7 signify for a minor chord?
Thanks 
Jem.

Comment: Are you certain it's a minor chord? I think the most likely is that it's a major 7 chord written out unclearly - should say Emaj7 and somehow all that's been printed is Emj7, so it looks like a minor chord with an unexpected j7 superscript. Conventionally major 7 chords have MAJ written in capitals.

Comment: Indeed you are correct Brian. But in the same tune maj appears... in the meantime I think it relates more to a piano chord. Thanks for your interest anyway. Jem.

Comment: Is the "j" supposed to be there? Have you seen "maj7" and this is something different? Can you perhaps add an image or a link to where you've seen the "j" before?

Comment: I have taken a photo of the sheet Todd. How do I upload?....

Comment: I believe I found the answer: Am(maj7). Looked at a sheet example with tabs.  Thank anyway.

Answer (score 2):

It's a way of writing 'maj7'.   Cm(maj7) could be written as Cmj7.  Not something I see a lot - and not something I'd recommend, too easy to confuse with Cmaj7 - but it's documented.  Just Google "chord j7".

[https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=chord+j7&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=eb9UWo-HD4z38AfMr6uQDQ](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=chord%20j7&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=eb9UWo-HD4z38AfMr6uQDQ)